# Is this proof for 1/4 mod 9 = x, correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find an integer x so (1/4) mod 9 = x

**Proof:**

```
> 1/4 mod 9 = x 
> 1 mod 9 = 4 * x
> - using x = 7 - 
> 1 mod 9 = 28 
> 28 mod 9 = 1 (to validate)
> - using Euler division theorem m = nq + r - 
> 28 = 9(3) + 1
> r = 1, so 1 = 1
```

I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: i get 4.7=1+3.9, so 7=1/4 + 3/4.9, so 7==1/4 mod 9

Comment: yes, with my proof, I am saying that x = 7, but I am not sure if the procedure used is valid. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $xy\equiv1\mod n$, so logically it makes sense to write $x\equiv\frac1y \mod n$

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was not sure.

Comment: typically doesn't work if $x|n$ or $y|n$ @JuanZamora

Answer (score 1):

Here is a systematic approach to finding the inverse.

Since $\gcd(4, 9) = 1$, $4$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $9$.  To find it, we must solve the equivalence 
$$4x \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$$
To find the solution, we can use the Euclidean Algorithm.
$$9 = 2 \cdot 4 + 1$$
Solving for $1$ yields
$$9 - 2 \cdot 4 = 1$$
Hence, $1 \equiv -2 \cdot 4 \pmod{9}$, so
$$x \equiv -2 \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$$
Therefore, 
$$4^{-1} \equiv \frac{1}{4} \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$$